# TypeError: Cannot read property 'taxTypeId' of undefined at Object.View_FullEditTaxComponent_0._co [as updateDirectives]

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a details form that should load the details of a record by when selected from the List Form. When the details form loads, it supposed to show the details of the selected record. In my case, it shows the details quite alright but it displays the titled error on the console, causing the application to crash.

**HTML (line of error)**

```
<select id="taxTypeId" name="TaxTypeId" [(ngModel)]="tax.taxTypeId" class="form-control" >
   <option *ngFor="let tt of taxTypes" value={{tt.id}}>{{tt.name}}</option>
</select>
<label for="taxTypeId" class="form-label">Tax Type</label>
```

**Typescript**

```
import { Component, ViewChild, Injector, Output, EventEmitter, ElementRef, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterLink, Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { TaxServiceProxy, TaxDto, ListResultDtoOfTaxTypeDto } from '../../../shared/service-proxies/tax-service-proxies';
import { TaxTypeDto } from '../../../shared/service-proxies/taxType-service-proxies';
import { AppComponentBase } from '@shared/app-component-base';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-full-edit-tax',
  templateUrl: './full-edit-tax.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./full-edit-tax.component.css']
})
export class FullEditTaxComponent extends AppComponentBase implements OnInit {
  active: boolean = false;
  saving: boolean = false;
  tax: TaxDto;
  taxTypes: TaxTypeDto[] = [];

  @Output() fromSave: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

  constructor(
    _router: Router,
    injector: Injector,
    private _taxService: TaxServiceProxy,
    private route: ActivatedRoute
  ) {
      super(injector);
      this.router = _router;
   }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadData();
    this.getTaxTypes();
  }

  loadData(): void {
    let id = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
    this._taxService.get(id)
    .subscribe((result: TaxDto) => {
      this.tax = result;
    })
  }

  getTaxTypes(): void {
    this._taxService.getTaxTypes()
    .subscribe((result: ListResultDtoOfTaxTypeDto) => {
        this.taxTypes = result.items;
    });
  }

}
```

How do I resolve this please?

Comment: The selected option is supposed to be the one whose value is equal to `tax.taxTypeId`, but `tax` is not initialized, thus undefined, and it's thus impossible to read the value of `tax.taxTypeId`. Initialize `this.tax`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're loading data asynchronously the `tax` property is `undefined` at first. And when angular performs change detection it is trying to get value from `[(ngModel)]="tax.taxTypeId"` binding and therefore you're getting the error.

There are many ways to solve the issue:

1) Safe navigation operator

```
[ngModel]="tax?.taxTypeId" (ngModelChange)="tax.taxTypeId && tax.taxTypeId = $event"
```

2) Initialize property with predefined value

```
tax: TaxDto = new TaxDto();
```

3) Wrap template in `*ngIf="tax"`

```
<select *ngIf="tax" id="taxTypeId" name="TaxTypeId" [(ngModel)]="tax.taxTypeId" ...>
   <option *ngFor="let tt of taxTypes" value={{tt.id}}>{{tt.name}}</option>
</select>
```